# CFWheels - Why is allErrors() returning an empty array?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

Yep... (me...again!)

I am trying to troubleshoot some errors and when I go to dump allErrors() in my controller, it is simply an empty array, when I know for a fact it shouldn't be.

**link.cfc (model)**

```
<cffunction name="init">

<cfset validate(property='linkURL', method="validateUniqueUrl", when="onCreate") />

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="validateUniqueUrl" access="public">
        <cfif this.exists(where="linkURL='#this.linkURL#'")>
            <cfset this.addError(property="linkURL", name="linkExists", message="The link you entered already exists.") />
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
```

If the link exists, I get the error correctly in my view:

```
<cfoutput>#errorMessagesFor("link")#</cfoutput>
```

However, in my controller, I want to dump all errors on the model by doing:

```
<cfdump var="#link.allErrors()#" abort />
```

Just a blank array! WTF?!

Even if I then try:

```
<cfdump var="#link.errorsOn("link")#" abort />
```

...again, an EMPTY array.

What in the world is going on here? Am I being an idiot or something?

Thanks.
Michael.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so it seems using `<cfdump var="#link.allErrors()#" abort />` in my view works, but not in the controller? Why not? I need this in the controller so that I can then make a redirect!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out myself. Typical that this always happens minutes after I post the question. Lateral thinking??

I had to call the `errorsOn()` method AFTER the `link.save()` method.

I was declaring this into a variable BEFORE the link.save() method...so I guess CFWheels never knew at that point that there were errors...because obviously you have t attempt a save before knowing it errors right?

BHAM! Logic.